# Query slow with literal and fast with variables - Oracle/Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, variables, toad

I have 2 queries : with literals in 13s and with variables in 60ms.

I tried to put "to_date" in literals, but nothing changed, 13sec

this in 13 sec, cost 49.338 , cardinality 4 (full table access):

```
select *
from registros, pagamentos
where 
    REGISTROS.DT_REGISTRO <=  '10/06/2019' and REGISTROS.DT_REGISTRO >= '10/06/2018'
    and dt_sistema<= '10/06/2019' and REGISTROS.DT_SISTEMA >= '10/06/2018'
    and REGISTROS.DT_COMPETENCIA <= '10/06/2019 'and REGISTROS.DT_COMPETENCIA >= '10/06/2018'
    and PAGAMENTOS.SQ_PAGAMENTO = REGISTROS.PAGTO_SQ_PAGAMENTO ;
```

this in 60msec , cost 14.412, cardinality 1:

```
select * 
from registros, pagamentos
where 
    REGISTROS.DT_REGISTRO <= :p_data and REGISTROS.DT_REGISTRO >= :p_data2
    and dt_sistema<= :p_data  and REGISTROS.DT_SISTEMA >= :p_data2
    and REGISTROS.DT_COMPETENCIA <= :p_data  and REGISTROS.DT_COMPETENCIA >= :p_data2
    and PAGAMENTOS.SQ_PAGAMENTO = REGISTROS.PAGTO_SQ_PAGAMENTO ;
```

Comment: try change the execution sequence  ..(seems a caching issue)

Comment: Run an explain plan on each query and post the results.

Comment: This: `'10/06/2019'` is a string. If columns you're comparing it with are `date` datatypes, Oracle has to perform implicit conversion. Try to use dates; date literal could be a good choice here, e.g. `and dt_sistema <= date '2019-06-10'`

Comment: When testing this, flush the buffer cache before running each query to ensure the 2nd query is not faster because it is provisioned by the buffer. Then you can truly compare the 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables

pay attention to bind variables and shared poola